# ImageJ macro that can select "no" when prompted with "Process Stack?"

Tags: process, stack, imagej

I have an imageJ macro that involves drawing a line on one slice of a stack. This works great but the only thing that slows this down is the prompt "Process all ### images? There is no Undo if you select 'Yes'."

Is there a way for me to have the macro automatically select "No" when this prompt appears?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the *"Process stack?"* dialog by running the *Draw* command with an option string containing a single space:

```bs
run("Draw", " ");
```

This will only draw on the current slice. If you instead want to draw on the whole stack, you can use:

```bs
run("Draw", "stack");
```

**EDIT**:
The [bug](http://fiji.sc/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190) causing incorrect macro recording (`run("Draw");`) when using the *D* shortcut was fixed in a recent [commit](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/commit/655ab6c): it now records `run("Draw", "slice");`